# Class.getResource(String) with Gradle Java project structure

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Given the following Java project structure:

```
ProjectFolder
 |- src
 |   |- main
 |   |   |- java
 |   |   |   |- foo
 |   |   |   |   |- view
 |   |   |   |   |   |- FooBar.xml
 |   |   |   |   |- FooBar.java
 |   |- test
 |   |  |- ...
```

Using a simple project structure **without** the `/main/java`and `test/java` folders in `FooBar.class` I could access `FooBar.xml` easily with

```
final URL url = FooBar.class.getResource("view/FooBar.xml");
```

However with the file structure above this is not possible.

What does the trick in this case? Any simple solution for that?

Edit: I realized that this - of course - is not a problem with Java but with IntelliJ IDEA:

With this IML file it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

However, with this one it does not

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id="SpinChatNotifier" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.system.id="GRADLE" external.system.module.group="" external.system.module.version="0.1" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/main" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/test" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.testng:testng:6.9.10" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: org.beanshell:bsh:2.0b4" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: com.beust:jcommander:1.48" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you try placing the XML file in `src/main/resources`? That is where your resource files go for the second IML structure

Comment: @cricket_007 No I did not; problem is that the JavaFX Scene Builder expects the FXML files in the same folder as the corresponding Java class.

Comment: I see. I haven't used the JavaFX builder. Also, this actually *is* a Java problem, not an IntelliJ problem, as you seem to think. IntelliJ just happens to setup the classpath of your project with the `src/main/java` structure.

Comment: @cricket_007 Well, if I do not build my Java project from a Gradle template it works fine, even with IntelliJ :-( Is there a way to include the FXML files into the classpath?

Comment: @cricket_007 The problem with an other location than the actual java src folder is, that Scene Builder won't recognize the corresponding controllers :-(